# What is the added value of return types in PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7, return-type

PHP 7 added return types. Other than more readable code, what are the advantages of specifying return types? Does this enable PHP to optimise performance in any way? Something else?

Comment: Essentially the same as: *What's the value of type hints in general?*

Comment: another important note, that type hinting isn't a new feature that came with php7 , actually in php7 type hinting is called [type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

I think that feature don't bringt some performance improvements. But you can be sure that the function you call give the return you expect.

That can prevent some problems. So if you call a function that is defined as int and you return in that function a string you get an error.